# how to set default value as text and auto increment in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, wechat

I am trying to set the default username as like wechat which have something like wxid_1234 
so can we set default username in our mysql table?

There is a table named 'username' and have two columns: 'username' and 'phone'. Since 'username' needs to be set something like foo_123 and may be auto increased with foo_124, foo_125 etc. It could be changed afterwards.

So is it possible to set the username like that?
if not what is the other method to do it.

Comment: No. `AUTO_INCREMENT` only works on integer types. Period. EOF.

Comment: @Sammitch Shouldn't that be EOS? ;)

Comment: Just do a concatenate on the columns via PHP. `$username . "_" . $id` - *Done deal*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but it would be two queries, and you would have to have an autoincrementing `user_id` as another column:

```
$sql = $dbo->prepare('INSERT INTO users(username, phone) values("temp", ?)');
$sql->execute(array($phone_number));
$id = $dbo->lastInsertId(); 
$sql = $dbo->prepare("UPDATE users SET username=? WHERE id=?");
$username = "foo_" . $id;
$sql->execute(array($username, $id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following approach:

- Create an `id` column set to `int` and AUTO_INCREMENT
- Create a username column set to VARCHAR with a DEFAULT value of `foo` or `foo_`
- Create a phone column set to VARCHAR

Then concatenate the `id` and `username` like this: (Using PHP)

```
$username . "_" . $id
```

or

```
$username . $id
```

depending on which method you'll want to use.

which will produce `foo_1` `foo_2` `foo_3` etc. respectively. The numbers will increase automatically from thereon.